# separating an array into comma separated values

Tags: awk, command-line, csv, nmap

I have a small snippet which gives me some ips of my current network:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "network:" network
data=$(nmap -sP $network | awk '/is up/ {print up}; {gsub (/\(|\)/,""); up = $NF}')
```

it returns ip addresses like this

```
10.0.2.1
10.0.2.15
```

and so on.

now I want to make them look like this:

```
10.0.2.1, 10.0.2.15, ...
```

I'm a total bash noob ,plz help me :)

Comment: Add in the end of your awk `ORS=", "` and you will have the result you want, with a small disadvantage (a trailing comma).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need exactly ", " as separator, you could use

```
echo "$data" | xargs | sed -e 's/ /, /g'
```

or if you are enough with comma as separator, then

```
echo "$data" | paste -sd, -
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* modify your `awk` script so that it returns a list of IP addresses delimited by a comma and a space but joining a list of items with a specific delimiter is such a common task that it's better to have a re-usable tool (script, function, compiled program, whatever) to do that.

Several languages (like `perl`) have such a function built-in.  Unfortunately, bash is not one of them....but it's fairly easy to write:

```
# perl-like join function for bash
join_by() {local d=$1; shift; printf '%s' "$1"; shift ; printf '%s' "${@/#/$d}"; echo;}
```

Put that in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` and you'll always have it available.

This is modelled on the perl `join()` function, but is named `join_by` so that it doesn't conflict with the standard `join` program (which joins lines in files).

The first argument is the delimiter.  All remaining arguments are the data to be joined.

For example:

```
$ data=$'10.0.2.1\n10.0.2.15'
$ join_by ', ' $data
10.0.2.1, 10.0.2.15
```

This particular usage is not recommended.  It relies on the shell word-splitting the **un-quoted** `$data` variable on whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc).  That is something that should be avoided where possible...I've included it here only because you are capturing the `nmap` output into a single string variable.

You should be using an array instead.  Like this:

```
data=( $(nmap -sP "$network" | awk '/is up/ {print up}; {gsub (/\(|\)/,""); up = $NF}') )
```

That puts each IP addressed returned by your `nmap | awk` pipeline into a separate element of the `$data` array.

here's a contrived example of how you'd join an array with `join_by`:

```
$ data=(10.0.2.1 10.0.2.15)
$ join_by ', ' "${data[@]}"
10.0.2.1, 10.0.2.15
```